# System.Uri.ToString not encoding some characters

Tags: c#, .net

I made a simple test to check how the automatic escaping from `Uri` works. I observed the following behavior:

- A character gets encoded automatically
- A character gets removed automatically
- A character isn't changed at all

I find this very inconsistent. What are the rules that decide when one of the above options apply?

```
var uri = new Uri("http://a? ");
Assert.True(uri.IsWellFormedOriginalString()); // Uri ignores the blank
Assert.AreEqual("?", uri.Query); // Uri trims the blank
Assert.AreEqual("http://a/?", uri.ToString()); // Again Uri trims the blank
Assert.AreEqual("http://a/?", uri.AbsoluteUri); // Same

uri = new Uri("http://a? %");
Assert.False(uri.IsWellFormedOriginalString()); // Uri knows that something is unescaped
Assert.AreEqual("?%20%25", uri.Query); // Uri replaces " " with %20
Assert.AreEqual("http://a/? %25", uri.ToString()); // Uri leaves the unencoded " " but encodes "%"
Assert.AreEqual("http://a/?%20%25", uri.AbsoluteUri); // Correct but not RFC 3986 (would require +%25)
```

I guess it's best to use `Uri.AbsoluteUri` instead of `Uri.ToString` but that requires a dummy scheme and authority for relative uris. Another solution might be to parse the query string yourself split it into parameters and then use `WebUtility.UrlEncode` on the parameter names and values before passing it to `Uri` with the rest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The outputs are expected as per design.

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.tostring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for `Uri.ToString` (emphasis mine):

> A String instance that contains the unescaped canonical representation
>   of the Uri instance. All characters are unescaped **except** #, ?, and %.

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.query%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for `Uri.Query` (emphasis mine):

> The query information is **escaped according to RFC 2396 by default**. If
>   International Resource Identifiers (IRIs) or Internationalized Domain
>   Name (IDN) parsing is enabled, the query information is escaped
>   according to RFC 3986 and RFC 3987.

There's more detail about when and in which order these changes take place, if at all, in the `Remarks` section of the [Uri page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not familiar with those specs. Why doesn't it just escape all special characters? Any reason for those exceptions? Also the `ToString` docs don't mention that unencoded chars also might get removed like in my first `ToString` example.

Comment: I'm not sure why the specs were designed in such a way. Regarding the missing unescaped query, I don't know how valid a space is at the end of a URL. Seems like .NET handles those by trimming them so they should be encoded, as you mentioned, before passing it in (assuming they're significant). If you add any character after it, regardless if they're safe or not, the space should be encoded since it's no longer a trailing space.

Comment: Another thing is that `ToString` docs say that `?` gets escaped but `http://a??` gives `http://a/??` which makes more sense anyway because `?` is not a special char.

Comment: ToString says "All characters are unescaped *except* #, ?, and %" so ? shouldn't be escaped in ToString